# How to exclude dependencies when building haddocks?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haddock

Is there any way to build haddock docs for specific packages? I'm trying to build haddocks for my package/app alone, but the following command seems to be doing this for all dependencies, as well:

```
stack haddock webservice
```

(where `webservice` is the name of my package/app)

Comment: There's a good reason to also build the docs for all dependencies: it makes sure the links will actually work! Cabal-install doesn't do this, which is not always a blessing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flag you're looking for is `--no-haddock-deps` as in

```
stack haddock --no-haddock-deps webservice
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. Does it also build the package itself, along with generating the docs? It seems the compiling everything to `.o` files. Any way to avoid that and generate JUST the docs?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with stack. I'm not sure if there are other ways to achieve that.

Comment: This command ends with a bunch of `Missing documentation for` warnings; reports `Completed 25 action(s).`; but then also says `Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1`. In `.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-9.0/8.0.2/doc/webservice-0.1.0.0` the only file is `LICENSE`. A few other packages have documentation in `.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-9.0/8.0.2/doc/` which seems to be completely generated. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The warnings aren't unusual. Is there no error message somewhere that could be connected to the ExitFailure? Also: did you start with a clean project, i.e. no `.stack-work`? If you could tell me how to reproduce the issue, I could possibly say more…