# Getting stack to build only haddock docs and not the library/executable

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haddock

Following up from [How to exclude dependencies when building haddocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50175379/how-to-exclude-dependencies-when-building-haddocks) I'm stuck in the following loop:

1. Run the following command: `stack haddock --no-haddock-deps webservice`
2. Wait for the `webservice` library to be built
3. Haddock then starts processing from the very first source file
4. Haddock fails on some trivial parse error related to comments
5. Fix such parse errors
6. Go to step 1

Is there any way to get stack/haddock to start from where it errored out, without going through steps (2) and (3) above?

Comment: Does stack not cache `webservice` in this case? It certainly does if you just once `stack build` the project, doesn't it? If not, then this sounds like one more reason to use `cabal` instead during development. I say this often... `stack` is a great _release tool_, but IMO less than optimal for development.

Comment: if you're writing haddocks for a module deep within the module hierarchy, it change the source file, which triggers recompilation of a lot of files.

Comment: Yeah but surely not files _from another library_?

Comment: I think that you can get the comment parse errors a bit earlier if you add `-haddock` to your ghc options. To shorten the build time you can try `-fno-code`.

Comment: `-fno-code` doesn't really work. It "builds" the entire project, but aborts with the following before haddocks can be built - `Warning: the following files would be used as linker inputs, but linking is not being done:`

Comment: @SaurabhNanda: You may be interested in the ongoing [Hi Haddock GSoC project](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/5706672807346176/#4975710121230336). If all goes well, haddock generation will soon no longer require rebuilding the library.

Comment: Not strictly what I think your after, but may still be helpful to you: use stacks `--file-watch` to ease your suffering somewhat.